# Validating receipt from macOS App Extensions?

Tags: swift, macos, receipt-validation, macos-app-extension

How a macOS [App Extension](https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/) can validate the app store receipt? That is, to verify whether in-app purchases for the app is valid (and continues to be valid)

Apparently the main bundle points to the App Extension's bundle hence the `appStoreReceiptURL` property `Bundle` returns a non-existing receipt file — even when the main app has the App Store receipt file.

For example, the following code prints out the main bundle and app store receipt paths, respectively.

```swift
let mainBundle = Bundle.main
print("main bundle path: \(mainBundle.bundleURL)")
print("receipt path: \(String(describing: mainBundle.appStoreReceiptURL))")
```

When placed inside an App Extension view controller's `viewDidLoad`, it returns results like these:

```
main bundle path: file:///Users/${userName}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/${projectBuild}/Build/Products/Debug/${mainAppName}.app/Contents/PlugIns/${appExtensionName}.appex/
receipt path: Optional(Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt -- file:///Users/${userName}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/${projectBuild}/Build/Products/Debug/${mainAppName}.app/Contents/PlugIns/${appExtensionName}.appex/)
```

However looking at inside the `.appex` bundle, the folder `Contents/_MASReceipt/` does not exists.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I’m guessing we could copy the receipt to a group container from the main app, but that seems fragile.

Comment: That's what I did. The main app copies the receipt after it passes validation. The extension would re-validate the copy of the receipt whenever it runs.

Comment: It is 2022, Is there a better way by now to access appStoreReceiptURL within the extension? The problem is, the users need to open the main app on a regular basis in order to have an up-to-date receipt information.